# CORS and HTTP authentication

Tags: javascript, php, http, cors

I'm trying make some ajax queries from domain `A` to domain `B` which is behind HTTP basic auth

Here is my Jquery (1.9.1) ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    data: s,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa('user:pass')
    },
    url: "http://domainB/script.php",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And script.php

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domainA');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

/**
 * Some stuff here
 */

echo json_encode( $json_response );
```

For some reason I ignore, I got this error in javascript console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://domainB/script.php' from origin 'http://domainA' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I don't understand what the error is, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set...

I tried many solutions found a little bit everywhere but without success.. May someone have a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190405/discussion-on-question-by-akio-cors-and-http-authentication). Please make sure to [edit] the question to incorporate all requested information.

Comment: This answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/970420/disabling-apache-basic-authentication-for-options-requests worked for me. I used in in a .htaccess file.