# If CORS wildcard for authentication not allowed, how to facilitate cross-origin authentication?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, cors

I'm getting a CORS error related to an AJAX (HttpClient) request which tries to receive `res.cookie` in response.

By way of background:

My CORS policy

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*',cors());
var allowCrossDomain = function(req,res,next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();  
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.use(csp({
  policies: {
      'default-src': [csp.NONE ],
      'img-src': [csp.SELF] }
}));
```

Request (from localhost:4200)

```
// Template
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="doSignUp(f)">
   . . . 
   . . . 
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>


//Sign-up Component
doSignUp(f: NgForm) {
  this.member.postSignupForm(f).subscribe((res)=>console.log(`RES: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`));
}


// Auth Service 
postSignupForm(f: NgForm): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.signup_url, f.value);
}
```

Response (from localhost:3000/users/sign-up route)

```
 . . . 
 . . . 
 user.save().then(()=> {
     res.cookie("SESSIONID", user.generateJWT(), {httpOnly:true, secure:true});
```

The error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I looked on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing and came across the following:

> A wildcard same-origin policy is also widely and appropriately used in the object-capability model, where pages have unguessable URLs and are meant to be accessible to anyone who knows the secret.

> **The value of "*" is special in that it does not allow requests to supply credentials, meaning it does not allow HTTP authentication, client-side SSL certificates, or cookies to be sent in the cross-domain request.**

The previous sentence has me very confused. If you can't use "8" to supply credentials, how do you configure CORS to allow HTTP authentication across origins?

I also noticed the following, apparently related question [CORS and HTTP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263246/cors-and-http-authentication), which has been outstanding for several months and has not been answered.

So, if Wikipedia is right, how do you allow a Cross-Origin AJAX request to result in a cookie being sent back in the response (for instance containing a JWT for authentication)? I must be missing something or mis-reading, but if you can't use "*" in Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but you want to have an open API, how do you authenticate people from random domains? You obviously can't know in advance all the domains that will be visiting your open website.

### Updates

Based on suggestions from the two answers below, I made changes as follows:

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept');

I now get a server-side "Duplicate Key" error:

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UserDB.users index: authData.username.value_1 dup key: { : "michael"}

I also still get a CORS error, but I think now the CORS error could be caused by the fact that the server has an exception. (I find that when the server has an exception, it often reflects in the client side CORS). Or does the server have an exception because the client is not receiving the response correctly because of CORS error?

The problem is, I believe I'm getting the duplicate key error because for some reason I can't figure out, the server is trying to save the same document twice. The document is being updated correctly in Mongo, but then the server tries to save the same document again. On the client side, there is only one post request.

Could this double-saving behavior have anything to do with the fact that the response from the server is not being accepted by the client because of CORS? I.e. is CORS causing the dupl key error, or is the dup key error causing the CORS error? And what would explain the server trying to save the same document twice?

Comment: Your new problem is totally unrelated to the old.  You're getting a CORS error because the server is sending an error response without the appropriate CORS headers.

Answer (score 2):

> THE PREVIOUS SENTENCE HAS ME VERY CONFUSED! IF YOU CAN'T USE "*" TO SUPPLY CREDENTIALS, HOW DO YOU CONFIGURE CORS TO ALLOW HTTP AUTHENTICATION ACROSS ORIGINS?

The server can choose to respond with a specific `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header that matches the `Origin` header from the request.

For example, suppose the client requests:

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1
Origin: origin-a.example.com
```

The server can respond:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: origin-a.example.com
```

In your Node.js example, try something like this:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || '*');
```

Comment: Many thanks. That's extremely helpful, and I feel as though this puts me on the right track. Unfortunately, however, after making the change you suggested (res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || '*') I'm still getting the CORS error. I note (as per console) that `req.headers.origin` is http://localhost:4200. Could there be an issue in the fact that the `origin` is `http`, while the `host` is `https`? Or if that's not a problem, any other thoughts about how I can further debug this?

Comment: I made some updates to the OP. Please see above, thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for NodeJS to support cross-origin requests, you need to specify the methods and headers explicitly. ie., the headers such as `Authorization`, `Origin` and `Accept` needs to be specified.

Another point to note is that when a browser sends cross-origin requests to the server, it primarily sends `OPTIONS` request to check the communication options for the target resource. This needs to be handled.

You can use something like this.

```
const app = express();
app.all('/', cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept"
  );
  if ("OPTIONS" === req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Hope this clarifies your concern.

Comment: Many thanks. That's very helpful. As per your suggestion, I added `res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept"
  );` and that seems to have helped to some degree, but I'm still getting an error (though slightly different now). I revised my OP as above. Many thanks if you'd please check the update, and see if you can think of any further suggestions!

Comment: @Crowdpleasr Did you take a look in your DB. I think the key has a duplicate. This might be the reason for that exception. As shown in the error you provided, the username seems to be having a duplicate.